# Norm related to diophantine approximation?

Tags: sp.spectral-theory, nt.number-theory, diophantine-approximation

I'm trying to read this paper: *Bourgain, J.; Jitomirskaya, S.*, [**Continuity of the Lyapunov exponent for quasiperiodic operators with analytic potential**](https://doi.org/10.1023/A:1019751801035), J. Stat. Phys. 108, No. 5-6, 1203-1218 (2002), [arXiv:math-ph/0110040](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.math-ph/0110040). [Zbl 1039.81019](https://zbmath.org/1039.81019). [CiteSeerX](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.20.1813)

But I don't understand the norm they are using in (1.3). They write down the condition
$\vert\vert k\omega\vert\vert>C(\vert k\vert \log(1+\vert k\vert)^A)^{-1}$

($\omega$ is an irrational number, and I think $k$ is an integer), and say that this expression is a "strong Diophantine condition" on $\omega$.

Another line in the paper which may be illuminating is

"for $\vert k\vert\leq q/2, \vert kw-ka/q\vert<1/2q$ and hence $\vert\vert k\omega\vert\vert >1/2q$."

Here $a/q$ is a lowest terms fraction with property $\vert \omega-a/q\vert<1/q^2$.

Context suggests to me that the norm should be a related to how easy it is to approximate an irrational number with rationals, but they don't have a definition in the paper, and I don't think I understand Diophantine approximation well enough to guess what it is.

Comment: For people who don't want to download the paper, or don't have a subscription to the journal, please put some actual detail in this question. e.g. the formula for the norm, and write out the context yourself. Read http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask for reasons why.

Comment: Is it just the distance to the integers?

Comment: Charles: I don't think so. Or at least that suggestion doesn't clarify the second example in particular. My guess is that the norm is related to c(x) in the wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_approximation

Comment: Darren, I don't have access to Springer, but already your first borrowing makes clear that $k$ means and integer and $\|\ \|$ is the distance from a real number to the nearest integer (without the "strong" appearance of $\log(1+|k|)$, the estimate is guaranteed by Dirichlet's theorem.

Comment: Wadim and Charles, you're right. After thinking through more clearly, it has to be the distance to the integers. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: The link to `mathoverflow.net/howtoask` in a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/222486) above is broken, but a copy is saved on the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20120106200300/http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask). The current Help Center article can be found here: [How do I ask a good question?](https://mathoverflow.net/help/how-to-ask)